# SSH Public Keys not working against CloudBees Repositories

Tags: cloudbees

I'm trying to use git as my repository, and I keep getting the error: Permission denied (publickey).

I've tried generating keys on my computer and placing the generated key in my cloudbees account as well as my known_hosts file.

I've also tried adding the key listed in the Jenkins job that I created in my known_hosts, and I'm still unable to connect.

I'm not really sure how to obtain the correct key or how/where to go about placing the key in the correct places.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Danny

Comment: Are you using a Mac or PC?  Which OS version?

Comment: I'm using a Mac with OSX 10.7.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things to try shown at http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Git+-+Getting+Started#HTroubleshooting

That being said, it sounds like you're new to SSH, and the commands in the above FAQ may not help.

Generally speaking you will generate a public and private key pair. The public key (~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub / ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub) will be pasted into GrandCentral as shown in the link above.

Comment: Yea, I tried generating a key and pasted it in the GrandCentral as shown above but keep getting the same result.

Comment: Okay, so I just generated the keys using ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 and pasted the public key into the GrandCentral. I tried doing this before and it still didn't work(most likely user error heh). Thank you guys for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: I'm glad it worked; it can be tricky get SSH working the first time; but once you get everything configured it does work quite well.